# how to sort arraylist according to "."?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I created arrayList with this values

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.add("a.b.c");
 list.add("a.b.d");
 list.add("a.b.e.f");
 list.add("a.b.e.h");
```

I want to so sorting according to the number of '.'s in the string.

That is, the string that has the minimum number of  '.'s will become the first one.

I tried to do this,

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
         return findDot(a) - findDot(b)
    }

    private  findDot(String a ){
         String [] result = a.split("\\.")
         return result .length
    }

});
```

But it didn't work.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Define _didn't work_. What is the error/bug? You have to give us something to work with here - we're not psychic.

Comment: You missed returned type in findDot method.

Comment: please update the exact code you are using in the program. This code misses a lot of things.

Comment: by the way:there schould be no space between result and .length....

Comment: this is why they put an edit button there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me. The only thing you were missing was a return type for the method `findDot` and a couple semi-colons, and the space between `results .length`

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Hello {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

         list.add("a.b.e.h");
         list.add("a.b.c");
         list.add("a.b.e.f.h.g");
         list.add("a.b.d");
         list.add("a.b.e.f");


         Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
                public int compare(String a, String b) {
                   return findDot(a) - findDot(b);
                }

                 private int findDot(String a ){
                     String [] result = a.split("\\.");
                     return result.length;
                 }

            });

         for (String s : list) {
             System.out.println(s);
         }

    }

}
```

Output

```
a.b.c
a.b.d
a.b.e.h
a.b.e.f
a.b.e.f.h.g
```

If you just want it sorted the other way around, just change this

```
return findDot(a) - findDot(b);
```

to this

```
return findDot(b) - findDot(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your source code is wrong(it contains syntax error).

The right code is below:(It works but better code exists)

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return Integer.compare(findDot(a), findDot(b));
    }
    private int findDot(String a ){
        String [] result = a.split("\\.");
        return result.length;
    }
});
```

And I advise you that if you use compare, use Integer.compare(A, B) instead A - B because if A is too big and B is too small(e.g. -2918291) then A - B is overflow and it raise an error.

Comment: B can't be negative in this case.

Comment: You are right to avoiding this kind of code, but there will be no error in overflow, it will just be converted back to positive value and wrong answer will be returned

Comment: Yes, so this case can write A - B but it's prefer to use Integer#compare because if always write Integer#compare, then don't care about overflow and underflow that may cause IllegalArgumentException or odd phenomenon(odd sorting) when Collections.sort. So, I suggest always write Integer.compare(A, B) instead A - B.

Answer (score 1):

```
private  findDot(String a ){
         String [] result = a.split("\\.")
         return result .length
}
```

Change it as

```
private int  findDot(String a){
         String [] result = a.split("\\.");
         return result.length;
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that one `.` results in an answer of `2` so this method isn't really correct. It should sort correctly but it doesn't return the number of `.` in a given `String`.